# How to access GWT designer view on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I havent yet found a way to view GWT designer mode. I have installed gwt sdk, gwt designer and window builder on eclipse 4.2. View my installation details: [image: installation details]
I Can open a java file using window builder but cant see the source and design tabs at the bottom: [image: image 2]
Somebody help me figure out how to access designer mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out its a bug and i was able to access designer mode by clicking switching between to a different layout under Google > Web Toolkit > Designer preferences

Thanks for providing answers guys :)

Answer (score 3):

right click on the file and select open in designer

Comment: sadly I don't have an eclipse in front of me right now (forced to do vs :( ), so my help is a bit limited to my memory. I noticed you are trying to view the main. Try something simple like a class inheriting from horizontal panel. I found the designer can be odd at times so i am only guessing here, sry.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on your uibinder file (ui.xml).  Then select windowbuilder.  You may need to click "other" and then select windowbuilder from the list.